# Laravel - How to check which column is updated using Observers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to know about only one column which is bieng updated using observer

```
<?php


namespace App\Observers;


use App\OnsiteHistory;

class OnsiteHistoryObserver
{

    public function updated(OnsiteHistory $onsiteHistory)
    {
        if ($onsiteHistory->status == 'accepted'){

           // send email  

        }
    }
}
```

I want to check only status column is updated.
How do I can do that?

Comment: It would be easy to detect what is updating in the `updating` event instead of `updated`. In your case, if you did not manually stored somewhere the value you have updated, you cannot get it from the model itself as you are not storing history somewhere.

Comment: I am able to find the updated column using `$onsiteHistory->isDirty(['status'])`

Comment: Good to know! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the bit of research and looking in to the Laravel source I have found way to do it.

Laravel Elouqont provides a method `isDirty([])`

```
namespace App\Observers;


use App\OnsiteHistory;

class OnsiteHistoryObserver
{

    public function updated(OnsiteHistory $onsiteHistory)
    {
        if ($onsiteHistory->isDirty(['status']) &&  strtolower($onsiteHistory->status) == 'accepted'){

       dd('I am updated')


        }
    }
}
```