# Reset Password sending me localhost url laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i click on Reset Password and fill the email and submit it.. then I am getting email for reset but URL is localhost my project is on production server.

In my config\app.php:

`'url' => env('DB_HOST'),`

and 
I also try this : `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://yourtradelog.com'),`

this is my env. file

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
    MAIL_PORT=**7
    MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
    MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.E*****hSbq1IAhFC1tPQg.uFah8Jwtm6GY7lh10wGpA_CPU01ySmAC26HFylz_BFI
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your Trade Log"
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=****@yourtradelog.com
```

This is my reset...:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password Notification from YourTradeLog.com'))
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
        ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
}
```

Comment: is the mail send via `php artisan queue:work/listen` or sync with the rest of the code?

Comment: Try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: I have also done in server `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: i have done this also ` composer dump-autoload` but till localhost @FullSTack01

Comment: `php artisan queue:work/listen` should i do this command to server composer? @Quezler

Comment: i am just wondering wether you are queing the mails or running them sync with your code

Comment: also, you are passing `config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)` to the `url()` function, just `route('password.reset', $this->token, false)` should suffice if i recall correctly

Comment: Redirect Notice
 The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http:///password/reset/70384f2d1c3ade6d8b89d498a2cd3d6c63d9e42e0bbc8bedfdaee5b95bb3d7bc). **after removed** `config('app.url').` @Quezler

Comment: also don't use the `url()` function around it, just `route('password.reset', $this->token, false)`

Comment: my domain name `yourtradelog.com` where should i suffix this?

Comment: the `route()` function in laravel should automatically build the url for you, no need to use `url()` around it

Comment: now this is my line : ` ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'), route('password.reset', $this->token, false))`

Comment: good, what happens if you click on the link that outputs?

Comment: after clicking on link from email : `Redirect Notice The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http:///password/reset/70384f2d1c3ade6d8b89d498a2cd3d6c63d9e42e0bbc8bedfdaee5b95bb3d7bc) `

Comment: Thanks so much for you effort, its just little mistake. My problem solved. @Quezler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following commands

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Also in your `.env`

set the `APP_URL=http://yourtradelog.com`

Comment: I have done this and but till localhost URL in email

Comment: @KINNARI your have ```'url' => env('DB_HOST'),``` in your app.php?

Comment: @KINNARI I am asking about app.php

Comment: muaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!!!  thanks so much. i spent already a lot of hours behind this thing

Comment: can you look up please on my another question?

Comment: @KINNARI which one?

Comment: this is my question which is really complicated for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919822/wherenotbetween-giving-me-error

Comment: if i want to make `notification` when any record come to specific table... should i use any reference for it for laravel? @Adnan Mumtaz

Comment: @KINNARI use Notifiable trait on usr and have a look at Model Observers

Comment: Do you know any reference or tutorial?

Comment: @KINNARI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897547/laravel-how-to-check-which-column-is-updated-using-observers